# Linuxカーネルって今もモノリシックカーネルなんですか？

Tags: linux, kernel

Linuxカーネルって今もモノリシックカーネルなんですか？　それとも、Windows NTやmacOSのXNUのようにハイブリットカーネルなんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

その辺は用語定義「モノリシックカーネルって何」から入らないと読者によって定義が違って収拾がつかなくなりますが

- デバイスドライバは全部ローダブルモジュールを採用している＝マイクロカーネル
- デバイスドライバは全部組み込み＝モノリシックカーネル
- デバイスドライバの一部は組み込み、一部はモジュール＝ハイブリッドカーネル

って定義にすると、最近の [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) はハイブリッドと呼んでいいでしょう。 `lsmod` とか `modprobe` とかあるのがその証拠って事で。